# How can I get the "navigator" object in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I'm writing a ClojureScript / reagent program. But I don't seem to have the browser's "navigator" object available to me.

How do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I was being stupid.

It's

```
js/navigator
```